# I have a CSV file with more than 8 dimensions attributes datas, how can i visulasition those datas

Tags: dataframe

I have a CSV file with more than 8 dimensions attributes datas, how can i visulasition those datas. [here is the screenshot of part of the datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfYdM.png)

as you can see, In the data sheet, there are 30 days, and each day record 10 times datas at 10 time point, each time record 10 attribute. 
I tried to plot one attribut in excel, but as there will be 300 time points, so the time axis is shrinked. how can i visulaise the datas in a better way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiWP9.png)

Blockquote

Comment: Please share the data extract as text rather than an image.

Comment: As CSV is a datatype file that accessed by many languages the question is.... in which program-language would you like to see a result? (i.e.: creating a figure that can be shown when file loaded by e.g. excel or openoffice).

Comment: For now your question is way too broad and thus nonbody can help you specifically. Also post some trail code which show you tried to solve it yourself. Don't heistate to include links and short info from where you found a possible solution, modified it and didn't work in the end. That's part of the learning curve and for others to show that the answer should be in another direction.

Comment: @ZF007 I worked those datas in excel, and cos the timeline is too long, it has 300 points, so the chart of the timeline shrink, I think this visualization result is not clear, can you please teach me a better way to express the datas.

Comment: @JingHuang ... Now I understand your question based on your added information. However, as SO is specific about asking question/answer specific to programming and this currently isn't completely applying to its rules we should modify the question to fit its rules. If you know how to programming in python then I certainly can help you. CVS files can be read/write by python which means we can do some mean calculations for a bunch of data-points, etc.and add the result in a new tab. I've got a clear view of how to display it too. Please post the data of day 1 and 2 in table form in the question.

Comment: as text and not as picture  or link the cvs file itself. Leave the picture in the question as well but rename its tag to something that makes sense. "enter image description here" doesn't cut it ;-)

Comment: @ZF007 sorry I don't know how to upload my CVS file

Comment: paste your table in notepad and then copy into the question, followed by formatting?

Comment: @ZF007 it is too large, i tried but it did not work. but it is ok, i managed it myself, thanks for help .